# Reading the unsigned char from the file using << operator

Tags: c++, file

I should read unsigned char from file and I don't know is it a char or a number. I can use the " << " operator only.

So if unsigned char in a file is a char I have no problems, but if it is a number it does not read it into a variable .

Comment: It is unclear, if file contain "1", does it the character '1', which is the number 49 or it is the number 1?

Comment: @SHR it will be 49

Comment: `operator<<` is for **writing to** a stream. You need to use `operator>>` to **read from** a stream. But for single-char reads, consider using `get()` instead. `operator>>` is meant for *formatted* reads.

Answer (score 0):

Data in files does not have types. There are no "chars" or "unsigned chars" or "numbers".

A file contains *bytes*. Period.

It is down to you to decide how to interpret those bytes.

Typically we have a convention or "file format" to help us decide how to do that for some given file.